# Removing the description box when creating taxonomies

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

When creating taxonomy terms there is a custom descriptiom box called 'Term description textarea'. Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way I can think is to alter the form in a custom module (just tested this and it worked):

```
function mymodule_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['description']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: That was pretty much the way I was going down the only problem is I am using 'seven' administration theme, so did it but only works on that theme (in the template.php). So what you are saying is I create a custom module called form_tidy and tidy up all my unwanted fields using that module?

Comment: Yep exactly, if you put the code in a module it'll run regardless of what theme is being used at the time